# Ruby: leading zeros with already formatted string

Tags: ruby

I can't understand why this happens:

```
s = "000301"
"%06d" % s             ====> "000193"
sprintf("%06d", s)     ====> "000193"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it was interpreted as an octal number.

Try it in irb:

```
> 0301
=> 193
```

But when you write:

```
> 301
=> 301
```

If you want to make it work, try to convert it to integer with [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
"%06d" % s.to_i
sprintf("%06d", s.to_i)
```

Comment: I was writing the same solution. Thanks ;)